# For brownian motion, why $dW_{t}=\epsilon\sqrt{dt}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I understand **ϵ** is sampled from Standard Normal distribution (since standard brownian motion)

but why does this make sense?

$$
dW_{t}=\epsilon\sqrt{dt}
$$

or the discrete form:

$$
ΔW_{t}=\epsilon\sqrt{Δdt}
$$

is there anything to do with quadratic variation?

Also what is this formula called?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explication why $\Delta W_t \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\epsilon \sqrt{\Delta  t}$ (or $dW_t \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\epsilon \sqrt{dt}$ )

$$\Delta W_t :=W_{t+\Delta}-W_t\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\mathcal{N}(0,\Delta t)=\sqrt{\Delta t}.\mathcal{N}(0,1)=\sqrt{\Delta t}.\epsilon$$

or

$$dW_t :=W_{t+dt}-W_t\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\mathcal{N}(0,dt)=\sqrt{dt}.\mathcal{N}(0,1)=\sqrt{dt}.\epsilon$$

Here, we used the [third property of Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process)

$$W_{t+u}-W_t\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\mathcal{N}(0,u)$$

Comment: I suspect that $\varepsilon \sqrt{dt}$ is not very well defined. It's better to show that
$$W_{\Delta t}=\varepsilon \sqrt{\Delta t}$$

Comment: @Snoop $\epsilon$ was already defined as Standard Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in the question. Besides, I agree that we write $\Delta t$ instead of $dt$ (the former is better). But write $dt$ is still correct also

Comment: it's the quantity $\sqrt{dt}$ and the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,dt)$ that I have some doubts about

Comment: @Snoop I don't get it. What and why you have doubts about $\sqrt{dt}$ and $\mathcal{N}(0,dt)$? You could consider $dt \in \Bbb R^+$

Comment: If you write $dt$ as a $\Delta t$ then I have no issues with those. However if $dt$ is 'infinitesimal' (I think OP is referring to this) then how is there a difference between the density of $\mathcal{N}(0,dt)$ and $\delta(x)$? Then the standardization starts to look suspect to me. I may be wrong though

Comment: @Snoop It's just a notation. And even if $dt$ is infinesimal (mathematically, it means $dt << 1$), I think there's still no problem. In fact, all equalities in my answer hold true if $dt >0$  (it's the sole necessary condition)

Comment: Hello @NN2, are you essentially suggesting that this is true because Var(dWt) = dt ? (since we can consider dWt as a sample drawn from) a Normal(0,dt) )

Comment: Also thank you @Snoop for your correction :)

Comment: @EJ Yes, you can say $V(dW_t) = dt$

Comment: @NN2 Thank you so much bro. It's all clear now :) You have my respect 

Comment: @EJ  You're welcome!

Comment: @NN2 does the notation make sense tho? dWt ∼ N(0,dt); how can you transfer that to 
dWt ∼ √dt N(0,1) (Can you write a distribution as such ?) or dWt = ϵ√dt ?

Comment: @E.J If you want to make things rigourous, you may replace all "d" by "$\Delta$" (for example: $dt$ by $\Delta t$, $dW_t$ by $\Delta W_t$). And we can write a distribution as such. I just modified the answer to erase all ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks @NN2 so you are allow to have a random process distributed by a scalar multiple times Standard normal distribution ?

Comment: @EJ Yes, it's the third property of Wiener process, as I mentionned in the answer.

Comment: kk cheers :)  @NN2